# How do I replace slash character "\'' by backslash character "/" in python

Tags: python, string, replace, path

I need to replace forward slash `"\"` with backward slash `"/"`.

I have tried:

```
c = "/r/tes/integr\test_\A\me.txt"
x = c.replace("\", "/")
print(x)
```

But I have got the error:

```
File "C:\Users\bwar1kor\Desktop\Test\test.py", line 33
    x = c.replace("\", "/")
                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: The string "/r/tes/integr\test_\A\me.txt" contains 2 backslashes. You probably thought there would be 3. Hint: Do you know what a raw string is?

Comment: You said you get the path dynamically, how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'\' is an escape character, to use the actual character itself you need to double it:

```
c = r"/r/tes/integr\test_\A\me.txt"
x = c.replace("\\", "/")
print(x)
```

Comment: with this getting "/r/tes/integr est_/A/me.txt" output, which is not valid

Comment: what do you mean "not valid". this is exactly what you asked for...

Comment: if you see, getting space after integer and /t is not there, please check it any idle

Comment: '\t' is also an escape character... add an "r" before the string to ignore escape characters

Comment: Ok , how can we use "r" for an variable, coz Iam getting that path in variable dynamic way

Comment: I think you can't. If the given string would have escape characters then when it's passed to you it would already apply them and you won't be able know